# scalac Scapegoat plugin for latest scala version

Tags: scala, sbt

In my current `sbt` project I'm using scala version (from build.sbt `scalaVersion`) is `2.11.12`. I want to upgrade this scala version to latest (`3.1.1`). In project `sbt-spacegoat` version is 1.0.7 When doing this I got the following error that

```
Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.sksamuel.scapegoat:scalac-scapegoat-plugin_3.1:1.3.3
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sksamuel/scapegoat/scalac-scapegoat-plugin_3.1/1.3.3/scalac-scapegoat-plugin_3.1-1.3.3.pom
[error] Error downloading org.scala-lang:scala-library:3.1.1
```

So when I checked in maven repo scapegoat is not for latest scala version `3.1.1`? How to solve this? Do I need to move out from scapegoat and use some other plugin?